# Linq with Logic

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have  simple Linq statement (using EF4)

```
var efCars = (from d in myentity.Cars
         where d.CarName == inputCar.CarName
         && d.CarIdNumber == inputCar.IdNumber
         && d.Make == inputCar.Make
         select d.Car);
```

I want it to be smarter so that it will only query across one or more of the 3 fields IF they have values.

I can do a test before, and then have a separate linq statement for each permutation of valyes for inputcar
(i.e. one for all 3, one for if only carname has a value, one for if carname AND CarIdNumber has a value etc etc)

but there must be a smarter way

Thanks!

Comment: I have trouble understanding what "query across one or more of the 3 fields IF they have values" means

Comment: note: i dont want to use LIKe statements, because if it being an unindexed search. id rather it be smarter to NOT test against a variable that is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "has no value" means null then you can use the null coalescing operator ?? to say take the first value if populated, otherwise take the second:

```
var efCars = (from d in myentity.Cars
where d.CarName == (inputCar.CarName ?? d.CarName
&& d.CarIdNumber == (inputCar.IdNumber && d.CarIdNumber)
&& d.Make == (inputCar.Make && d.Make)  
select d.Car);
```

This basically says if a value exists it must match, otherwise treat it as matching

However if instead you're saying "when a special value (empty string) ignore it, otherwise match" then you can do one of two approaches (or possibly more!):

```
where (inputCar.CarName == "" || d.CarName == inputCar.CarName)  

where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputCar.CarName) || d.CarName == inputCar.CarName)
```

Comment: @Anders Abel: I'm posting from a phone and it doesn't have a preview!  I went back to fix it but you'd already done it

Comment: thanks i like the idea but doesnt seem to work. maybe because my value is "" rather than null. could that b my issue?

Comment: verified. my values are "" instead of null so the ?? doesnt work. but i put a test saying: if carname == "" then carname = null. solves my probs. is this best practice tho?

Comment: I'd just updated the answer to that!  As per other answers you need to measure performance to check and not assume what is best. The code is readable which is important. readable code is definitely best practice!

Answer (score 1):

For performance (when dealing with database queries) it can sometimes be beneficial to let EF generate queries based on the filters, instead of using one generic query. Of course you will need to profile whether it helps you in this case (never optimize prematurely), but this is how it would look if you dynamically build your query:

```
var efCars =
    from car in myentity.Cars
    select car;

if (inputCar.CarName != null)
{
    efCars =
        from car in efCars
        where care.CarName == inputCar.CarName
        select car;
}

if (inputCar.IdNumber != null)
{
    efCars =
        from car in efCars
        where care.CarIdNumber == inputCar.IdNumber
        select car;
}

if (inputCar.Make != null)
{
    efCars =
        from car in efCars
        where care.Make == inputCar.Make
        select car;
}
```

Comment: I think that if you used method syntax, your code would be much shorter.

Comment: @svick: Yes, it would be less lines, but who cares about lines ;-)\

Comment: It would also be less code. And I think not having  to read through all the `from`s and `select`s would make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`where (inputCar.CarName != null || d.CarName == inputCar.CarName) &&...`